# Clear SMB network share credentials in OS X

Tags: macos, finder, smb, keychain

I'm mounting a Windows network share on OS X 10.7 without being asked for the credentials. How can I make OS X forget any stored credential so it asks me?

I've already searched all displayed items in the Keychain, but none looks like it belongs to the Finder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are called *Network Passwords* and don't actually belong to Finder.  You'll probably find them in your "login" keychain if you have a closer look (you can also search for the server's name).

> [image]

<sub>Never mind that this is a VNC password, it stores them for AFP and SMB as well.</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to clear them via shell command ?

Comment: If anyone else but wonders *how*?  Open Finder, the menu select "Go", then "Utilities", then "Keychain Access". Took me a good while to figure that one out... :-)